# Partly delete a key sequence?

Tags: keystrokes, which-key

I'm relatively new to Emacs, so apologies if I'm using any terminology incorrectly.

I have installed Doom Emacs in Evil mode, so command shortcuts are commenced with SPC instead of Meta. When entering a key sequence, a menu pops up to show me the available options for the next key (I believe this is provided by the `which-key` package).

What I would like to be able to do is to go back a step if I haven't found what I'm looking for in the current "menu", rather than having to abort and start from the beginning with a new key chord.

E.g.: I enter `SPC h d` (help -> doom). How can I delete the `d` to return to the first level menu, as opposed to starting again with `ESC SPC h`?

Comment: Also key chord is not correct word for this question(Since there is key-chord package) If you can change those with key binding this can be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found this from its Github page.

https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key#paging-options

Not one key but, If you press also for `C-h u` you can go for previous state.

> which-key-undo can be used to undo the last key press when in the middle of a key sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can rebind it now that I know the command.